# Error installing Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Error Traceback below.

```
import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django
```

[image]

Comment: I see `timed out` on screen. Maybe there is problem with server - try tommorow.

Comment: **PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**. Copy and paste the text into your question. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're installing django on a system level, then try installing via root like this

```
sudo pip install django
```

If you're in a virtualenv, then the a simple `pip install django` would also work.

To know what a virtualenv is, please refer: https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I see `The read operation timed out` - maybe there is problem with server or too many people try to use server at this time. Try to install tomorrow.

If you can download django on local disk as `whl` file then you can use

```
 pip install downloaded-django-package.whl
```

btw: it can be problem with `pip` so you can also try to upgrade `pip`

```
 pip install --upgrade pip
```

**EDIT:**

If you get error with `Permission denied` then you have to use `sudo` as @ishaar suggests.